# enable_if template param is lambda (with particular signature)

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++14, enable-if

I have something this:

```
template<typename T>
class Image {
    Image(int w, int h, T defaultVal){
        for(int i=0; i<h; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<w; j++)
                pixel(j, i) = defaultVal;
    }
    template<typename F>
    Image(int w, int h, F initializer){
        for(int i=0; i<h; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<w; j++)
                pixel(j, i) = initializer(j, i);
    }
    // ...
};
```

My intention is to be able to instantiate an `Image` like this:

```
Image<int> img0(w, h, 0); // image of zeroes
Image<int> imgF(w, h, [](int j, int i){ // checkerboard image
    return (j/10+i/10) % 2;
});
```

But of course the second constructor signature will conflict with the first constructor signature. To resolve this conflict I want to restrict the second constructor's possible template instantiations.

I don't want to make it too complicated. Can you help me? My attempt:

```
template<typename F, typename = std::enable_if_t< // what now? how to check that F is callable (and if simple to check, with appropriate signature)
```

Comment: Could `std::enable_if<std::is_function<F>>` help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for [`std::is_invocable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable):

```
template<typename F, typename = std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_invocable<F&, int, int>>
```

`F&` because you're invoking it as an lvalue, and then after that it's just a list of types of parameters.

---

The above requires C++17. It is implementable on C++14, but in your case we can also take a much simpler approach and just do:

```
template <typename F, typename = decltype(std::declval<F&>()(1, 1))>
```

`F&` for the same reason as above, and the rest of the expression is more familiar. Since we're calling with `int`s we don't care about the other things that `INVOKE` allows for (e.g. pointers to members).

Comment: Can you explain the practical difference the `F&` makes compared to `F`? Does this have to do with `std::ref`?

Comment: @MaxLanghof It has to do with reference qualifiers. Does the function object have different overloads of `operator()`? If so, you want to make sure you are checking the one you are actually using.

Comment: I see, you would have to check for `const F&` if you were invoking on a `const F&`.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Right, but we're just deducing `F`, so it wouldn't ever be const.

Comment: @MaxLanghof, consider call operator with ref qualifier: `void operator ()(int,int) &&;`. It can be only invoked on rvalue, and you are calling lvalue.