# How can I restrict lambda signatures in C++17 template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, constraints, c++17

Suppose I have two functions that receive different lambda types as arguments:

```
template<typename F>
void func1(F&& lambda) {
    // lambda must be [](unsigned int) -> short
}

template<typename F>
void func2(F&& lambda) {
    // lambda must be [](const vector<string>&) -> void
}
```

How can I restrict these lambda signatures in C++17, to match exactly what I need in each case?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50859251

Comment: Do you want to specifically restrict the signatures of *lambdas* or permit any given callable object type that can be called with a certain set of arguments?

Comment: @pasbi It could be, but it doesn't seem to validate the return type. I'm having hard time with the given example, it's not compiling.

Comment: @NicolBolas I want to restrict the signatures of the lambdas, including the return type.

Comment: @rodrigocfd: Well, you can't specifically restrict the signature of a **lambda** because there's no mechanism you can use to distinguish a lambda from any other callable user-defined type.

Comment: @NicolBolas What if I can also accept any callable that matches the arguments and the return type?

Comment: @rodrigocfd: That's why I asked if you wanted it to be specific to *lambdas* or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way that immediately pops to mind is to leverage `std::function` and its deduction guides. Using CTAD, the signature can be deduced automatically for certain types of functors (non-generic lambdas among them). It will look like this

```
template<typename F>
auto func1(F&& lambda) 
  -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<decltype(std::function{std::forward<F>(lambda)}), std::function<short(unsigned)>>> {
    // lambda must be [](unsigned int) -> short
}
```

`std::function{std::forward<F>(lambda)}` is a functional cast expression that attempts to convert the argument into a `std::function` whose template arguments get deduced. If the deduction is successful, we can obtain a type to compare against `std::function<short(unsigned)>`. With that in hand, we can use the usual SFINAE utilities in the standard library to constrain `func1`.

Mind however, that this doesn't constrain the function template only to *lambdas*, any functor for which the CTAD succeeds, and then matches the argument list, is going to be accepted.

Comment: It seems to work but my brain is melting now. I've never seen a function returning `->` before, where I can learn about it?

Comment: @rodrigocfd - That's just a [trailing return type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function). It's a declaration style introduced by C++. It works for all functions, so even `auto main() -> int {}` is valid. I just prefer it for code that does SFINAE on the return type, because to me personally it seem more readable.

Answer (score 4):

Pre C++20:

```
template<typename F, typename = std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_invocable_v<F, unsigned int>
>>
void  func1( F &&lambda ) {
    // lambda must be [](unsigned int) -> short
}
```

C++20:

```
template<typename F>
requires std::is_invocable_v<F, unsigned int>
void  func1( F &&lambda ) {
    // lambda must be [](unsigned int) -> short
}
```

Use std::is_invocable_r_v if you want to validate return type as well.

[EDIT]

... using std::is_invocable_r_v

```
template<typename F, typename = std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_invocable_r_v<short, F, unsigned int>
>>
void  func1( F &&lambda ) {
    // lambda must be [](unsigned int) -> short
}
```

Comment: Do you mind to write an example with `is_invocable_r_v`, validating the return type?

Comment: You entirely glossed over that point that this would accept every functor that can be called with these arguments (and not just *has* those argument types). It's a crucial difference. Now, granted, this may be the better alternative at the end (checking exact signatures is a somewhat limited use case), but to omit an explanation of the difference is to act remiss.

Comment: The return type is validated just as "convertible", right? (I mean, in this case my lambda can return `int` or `short`, since it's convertible.)